# How to optimise images in magento 1.9.x to speed up the page load

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, optimization

My images in site don't reduced size of image for Google PageSpeed Insights, when I input resize image in my site. Example image 1 , size of image 20 KB, I resized image reduced to 4KB and I input image on ftp server my site, then size of image to expand as 20 KB as before.

I would like extension to can help solve an issue eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content and optimize image for add score the Google PageSpeed Insight.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate render-blocking JS and CSS you would need to dig into the theme's layout and make changes there.

Render blocking JS in 99% of the cases is safe to move to the end of the `<body>` tag (after all the HTML has loaded) or using `async` or `defer` attributes. Moving CSS in a similar way can be tricky as it would load an unstyled version of the page first.

You can also refer to existing plugins like https://github.com/mediarox/pagespeed

For images, there are a couple of options. You can either try resizing and optimising using libraries like ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick and upload the images to your server. Or you can try using [ImageKit](https://imagekit.io) to optimise images automatically.

Comment: How to use ImageKit?

Comment: You can go through the documentation https://docs.imagekit.io 
Especially the Adding a web server as a source part in the Migration section.

Comment: I don't understand documentation of imagekit.io. Do you have Link Youtube of docs.imagekit.io? Thank you.

Comment: Steps for integration would be available on your email used for registration on ImageKit

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we do:

1. ssh to the server
2. download and install `jpegtran`, `optipng` , just google how to do that on your server
3. use this commands:

   ```
   find ./media ./skin ./js -type f -iname '*jpg' -exec sh -c 'jpegtran -outfile "{}.out" -optimize "{}"; mv "{}.out" "{}"' \; 
   find ./skin ./media ./js -iname '*.png' -exec optipng -o7 -keep -preserve '{}' \;
   ```

It might take a couple of hours if you have a big number of images

You might want to add these commands to cron to run every weekend

Comment: Magento Script might to error because images don't size reduce with resized images on ftp server. I don't know.